# Profiling WPF Loading Events

Tags: wpf, profile

I have a complex control that is taking a very long to Initialize. Whilst I am able to use the WPF performance kit to profile the controls Layout time, I haven't found a way to analyze initialization time.

Im wondering if there is any way I can analyze where the hot spot is in initializing the controls hierarchy, styles, resources etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any tool which will allow debugging or profiling the Initialization process.

you can use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see the visual tree.
you can use [pistachio](http://www.granthinkson.com/2007/11/08/announcing-pistachio-wpf-resource-visualizer/) to profile unused resources.

eventually you'll have to remove all UI elements from the control and start adding them one by one while counting the initialization time that way you'll be able to figure out the hot spot.
of course you have to take in account the binding in the specific use case which result in the performance hit